# What happened to VSTS when TF10167 arises? how could that be solved?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Sometimes, when I'm ckeckin out source code using Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 Professional, this error appears:

> "TF10167: An unsupported ConflictId was specified."

This forces me to copy source code and fix the problems by my own hand after I overwrite
my local workspace with server's source code version.

What's going on? How can I solve it?

Comment: We are using Visual Microsoft Visual Studio® Team System 2008

Comment: That's the Visual Studio version. What's the TFS version?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Comment: No, I mean what is the version of your Team Foundation Server that you are connecting to?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I think Juan means VSTS2008 (TFS2008) combined with VS2010.

Comment: @kroonwijk: I suspect so too, but since "VSTS" is a somewhat ambiguous term, I'm trying to make _certain_ of which version of TFS is being used.

Comment: @JohnSaunders do you need more information? I do not know how to get my TFS version from my programming terminal (without asking somebody)...

Comment: Asking someone would work for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a bug in TFS that has been fixed in TFS 11. It is possible that renaming a folder that has a conflict in a child item caused this to happen.

To overcome this error, the conflict needs to be removed from the database - however, you will need to contact [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support) and open a case to get them to help you with it. Seeing that this is likely a bug in the product, the support case should be free.

Although its a pain, recreating your workspace should also fix this problem.

I confirmed with the dev team that when your server gets upgraded to TFS 11, this gets detected and fixed automatically.